# Для чего в классах объявлять переменные?

Tags: php, ооп, функции, классы

Не подскажите, для чего в классах (`class`) можно объявить переменные? (`public $перемернная;`)

Можно же и в `function` передавать...

```
public function ...($переменные, ...) {}
```

А можно и в `function` вообще переменные получить через `global $переменная;` или `$_GLOBALS[];`.

Для чего нужны переменные в class'ах?

Просто получать их с помощью `$this->переменная`?

Comment: АХахахаха, тогда для чего нужны классы? Просто хранить набор функций?)

Comment: Для всех гыгыкающих и минусующих: это абсолютно законный вопрос для Stack Overflow - конкретный и  однозначный, ответ на который будет полезен множеству читателей.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Свойства (переменные) нужны в классах для сохранения состояния объектов. Наверняка, вы представляете себе класс, как набор функций сосредоточенных в одном месте. Если говорить о статик классах-хелперах, то, наверное, так и будет.

Но в большинстве своем используются объекты как модель области, а у модели есть какие-либо свойства.

Возьмем простой пример - игра, где есть два воина, и они наносят друг другу урон. Как вы адекватно сделаете без свойств(переменных) ?

Пример:

```
<?php
class Warrior{
    public $health;
    public $damage; 
    public function __construct($name, $health, $damage){
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->health = $health;
        $this->damage = $damage;
    }
    public function doDamage(Warrior $warrior){
        $warrior->health-=$this->damage;
    } 
}
$w1 = new Warrior('Petya',100,10);
$w2 = new Warrior('Vasya',80,8);


while(true){
    $w1->doDamage($w2);
    if($w2->health<=0){
        echo $w1->name.' Выиграл';
        break;
    }
    $w2->doDamage($w1);
    if($w1->health<=0){
        echo $w2->name.' Выиграл';
        break;
    }
}
```

Если бы не было объектов, было бы куча переменных для каждого воина. А если таких воинов 100? С объектами все удобнее и лакончинее.

Answer (score 1):

Есть два типа переменных, которые можно использовать для объявления в классах.

1. Статические
2. Динамические

Статические переменные  используются для хранения информации о классе целиком. 
Эти переменные очень похожи на глобальные переменные. Они тоже существуют в единственном числе для приложения. Но хранятся эти переменные не в глобальной помойке всех переменных на уровне приложения, а как бы привязаны именно к данному классу. Что облегчает их поиск и использование.
Примерами таких переменных являются: счетчик объектов данного класса, ссылка на какой-то конкретный объект данного класса (singlton), коллекция ссылок на объекты данного класса, параметры, используемые для инициализации объектов данного класса.

Динамические переменные используются для хранения данных конкретного объекта, созданного на основании данного класса. Эти переменные могут быть использованы только для уже созданного объекта через ссылку на этот объект (обычно это this). 
Примерами динамических переменных являются: имя персонажа, пол персонажа, уровень жизни персонажа, текущая сила персонажа...